# 2 out of 5 ceiling lights in basement won't work

Tags: electrical, lighting, basement, circuit-breaker, light-fixture

2 out of 5 ceiling lights in basement won't work. The fuse never tripped. The lights never flickered. They worked perfectly before. The house was built in 1997. The basement is unfinished so I can see the wires going into the fuse box and they look fine. I did try new bulbs and brand new fixtures but still no working light bulbs. I don't own an electrical reader or tester. Do I need an electrician to fix something in the fuse box?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 4):

If 3 out of 5 do work, and 2 out of 5 don't work, and it's all the same circuit (unclear if that's the case from your question) the problem is likely to be a failed connection between the working lights and the not working lights, rather than anything at the fuse box.

Since you have already tried replacing the fixtures, (which would presumably mean you have changed the connections at that end of the wire) the most likely location for the problem is at the last working fixture, where the wire runs on to the first not working fixture - speculating that they are wired in a linear manner, since that is also unclear from your question.